# how can I do a custom implementation of Bag of words for byte file?

Tags: python-3.x, bytecode, countvectorizer

I am trying to do a custom implementation of Bag of Words on the hex codes present in byte file. So the hex corpus would consist of a character like "??". 
I found this code for custom implementation of  Bow but it removes the "??" from the corpus.

```
# Replace all none alphanumeric characters with spaces
s="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0a,0b,0c,0d,0e,0f,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,1a,1b,1c,1d,1e,1f,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,2a,2b,2c,2d,2e,2f,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,3a,3b,3c,3d,3e,3f,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,4a,4b,4c,4d,4e,4f,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,5a,5b,5c,5d,5e,5f,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,6a,6b,6c,6d,6e,6f,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,7a,7b,7c,7d,7e,7f,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8a,8b,8c,8d,8e,8f,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,9a,9b,9c,9d,9e,9f,a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,aa,ab,ac,ad,ae,af,b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,ba,bb,bc,bd,be,bf,c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,ca,cb,cc,cd,ce,cf,d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,da,db,dc,dd,de,df,e0,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9,ea,eb,ec,ed,ee,ef,f0,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,fa,fb,fc,fd,fe,ff,??"
```

```
import re

def generate_ngrams(s, n):
    # Convert to lowercases
    s = s.lower()

    s = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', ' ', s)

    # Break sentence in the token, remove empty tokens
    tokens = [token for token in s.split(" ") if token != ""]

    # Use the zip function to help us generate n-grams
    # Concatentate the tokens into ngrams and return
    ngrams = zip(*[token[i:] for i in range(n)])
    return [" ".join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]
```

On removing this line: `s = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', ' ', s)`, it returns nothing

Comment: What does "hex codes present in byte file" mean? The code you show is to split a sentence into word n-grams: `['i am', 'am trying', 'trying to', 'to do', 'do a', 'a custom', 'custom implementation', 'implementation of', 'of bag', 'bag of', 'of words', 'words on', 'on the', 'the hex', 'hex codes', 'codes present', 'present in', 'in byte', 'byte file']` (and it has a typo in `token`).

Comment: @usr2564301  Hex code in the byte files has the characters that I mentioned in 's'.There is a '??' character in byte file which is causing error with the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression replaces every character that is *not* (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, any whitespace) with a single space. That includes the `?` that you want to keep. Add it to the exclusion set

```
s = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s?]', ' ', s)
```

to make it work (you'll also have to fix that inexcplicably typo in `token`).

The reason it returns 'nothing' if you remove the regular expression is because it only splits on *spaces* – of which there are none in the original string – and then returns each *pair* of words. You can't make a pair out of a single item.